# Is it possible to store data privately into the bitcoin blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, storage

Given that Bitcoin is a public and permissionless blockchain, does this mean that any data stored in it will be free for anyone to see?

Is it possible to store documents such as screenshots etc.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is blockchain really secure to store sensitive data?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/83001/is-blockchain-really-secure-to-store-sensitive-data)

Answer (score 4):

You can encrypt your data before you store it. However anyone would have access to the encrypted data and, if the encryption is broken (either now or in the future), the encrypted data will be revealed.